# What is the time complexity of this code containing two loops?

Tags: python, time-complexity

This is one of the solutions on LeetCode.

The problem:
Given an array of the revenue on each day, and an array of milestones a company wants to reach, return an array containing the days on which the company reached every milestone.

Input
revenues is a length-N array representing how much revenue company made on each day (from day 1 to day N). milestones is a length-K array of total revenue milestones.
Output
Return a length-K array where K_i is the day on which company first had milestones[i] total revenue. If the milestone is never met, return -1.
Example

```
revenues = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]
milestones = [100, 200, 500]
output = [4, 6, 10]
```

Explanation
On days 4, 5, and 6, company has total revenue of $100, $150, and $210 respectively. Day 6 is the first time that the compnay has >= $200 of total revenue.

They said the complexity is O(klogk) + O(n) but since there are two loops, a for loop of O(n) complexity and a while loop also of O(n), shouldn't it be O(n^2) + O(klogk) instead? If not, why the while loop isn't O(n)?

```
def getMilestoneDays(revenues, milestones):
  ret = [len(revenues)]*len(milestones)
  milestones = sorted([(x,i) for i,x in enumerate(milestones)]) #O(klogk)
  sums = i = 0 # sums is the current cumulative sum of revenues, i is the current index of sorted milestones
  
  for j,x in enumerate(revenues, start=1): #O(n)
    sums+=x
    while i<len(milestones) and sums>=milestones[i][0]:
      ret[milestones[i][1]] = j
      i+=1
  return ret
```

Comment: im not sure but i think is because the while loop cycles on ```i``` and ```i``` never gets resetted, ```i``` doesnt get set to 0 in the cycle, the code inside the ```while``` gets executed an ```n``` number of times, not an ```n^2``` number of times

Comment: You're question is somehow ill-asked, in the sense that it is possible for the complexity to be both `O(n²)` and `O(n)`, as the `O(...)` notation stands for an upper bound. It's like saying you can have `10 < 100` and `10 < 200`, even though `100 < 200`. In particular, the while loop is `O(n)`, and so the whole program is `O(n²)`. But that's not a good bound probably because, as @BestDogeStackoverflow says, the code inside `while` is also executed `O(n)` times, so in the end the whole thing is `O(n)`.

Comment: @BlackBeans But if the code inside the while loop is also executed ```O(n)``` times, then with the for loop, isn't that ```O(n*n) = O(n^2)```? Not sure I understand how can it be all together ```O(n)``` presuming we are looking into the worst case scenario.

Comment: @user2645029 I will rephrase what you just said, and hopefully it will make it clear to you: "But if the code inside the while loop is also executed at most `A×n` times, then with the for loop won't it execute at most `B×n×n=B×n²` times?" (`A` and `B` are two constants). The answer is: yes, it will execute at most `n²` times (up to a constant factor), but that is not incompatible with the proposition "it will execute at most `n` times" (up to a constant factor). With your analysis, you only get the quadratic bound, but that does **not** mean that a better analysis won't lead to a better bound.

Comment: And a better analysis is the following: the `while` loop will only iterate if `i < len(milestones)` (let's call `k := len(milestones)`). Furthermore, each time a `while` iteration is executed, `i` is incremented. Therefore, there can't be more than `k` `while` iterations **during the whole function** (regardless of during which iteration of the `for` loop these `while` iterations takes place). This means that you can count independently what happens inside the `for` loop, and what happens inside the `while` loop. In the `for` loop, besides the while loop, you have `O(1)` operations.

Comment: therefore, the `for` loop takes `O(n)` time at most. In the `while` loop, on the other hand, as just shown, the complexity is at most `O(k)`. Since we already have a `O(k×ln(k))`, we can neglect the `O(k)`, leading to a `O(n+k×ln(k))` overall.